# The function "org.apache.jena.rdf.model.hasProperty" didn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, rdf, jena

I'm learning jena recently.  
I try to understand their TUTORIALS. (https://jena.apache.org/tutorials/rdf_api.html#ch-Navigating-a-Model).  
When I compile Tutorial06, (https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/main/jena-core/src-examples/jena/examples/rdf/Tutorial06.java) 
I put a "/" in the end of the URI by accident in line 32: 
`static final String johnSmithURI = "http://somewhere/JohnSmith/";` 
(it should be: `static final String johnSmithURI = "http://somewhere/JohnSmith";`)  
so I got the exception.  
I want to use "org.apache.jena.rdf.model.hasProperty" to set a condition, 
but it didn't work.

There might be two situation:

1. if I directly copy and paste "`vcard.hasProperty​(VCARD.Family)`" 
   the console will show "The method hasProperty​(Property) is undefined for the type Resource" 
   it's strange 
   this method is defined in their doc 
   https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/rdf/model/Resource.html#hasProperty(org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Property)
2. However, if I just choose the function after I keyed in "." like the picture 
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axzgr.png) 
   It won't show the error 
   but the value of Boolean seems strange 
   I add those code since line 51 in Tutorial06: 
   `System.out.println("vcard.hasProperty(VCARD.FN) : " + vcard.hasProperty(VCARD.FN)) ; System.out.println("vcard.hasProperty(VCARD.N) : " + vcard.hasProperty(VCARD.N)) ; System.out.println("vcard.hasProperty(VCARD.Family) : " + vcard.hasProperty(VCARD.Family)) ; System.out.println("vcard.hasProperty(VCARD.Given) : " + vcard.hasProperty(VCARD.Given)) ; System.out.println("vcard.hasProperty(VCARD.EMAIL) : " + vcard.hasProperty(VCARD.EMAIL)) ;`

   Result:  
   `vcard.hasProperty(VCARD.FN) : true`  
   `vcard.hasProperty(VCARD.N) : true`  
   `vcard.hasProperty(VCARD.Family) : false`  
   `vcard.hasProperty(VCARD.Given) : false`  
   `vcard.hasProperty(VCARD.EMAIL) : false`

the rdf file look like this:  
`<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://somewhere/JohnSmith">`  
   `<vCard:FN>John Smith</vCard:FN>`  
   `<vCard:N rdf:parseType="Resource">`  
      `<vCard:Family>Smith</vCard:Family>`  
      `<vCard:Given>John</vCard:Given>`  
   `</vCard:N>`  
`</rdf:Description>`

I'll appreciate if anyone can give me some idea about those situation.  
I use Eclipse with jdk-11 and the jena-core -3.2.0.jar as my library

Comment: `jena-core -3.2.0.jar` is ancient. Also - use all the jars, not just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "vCard:Family" has a different subject because of the `<vCard:N rdf:parseType="Resource">`.

The RDF structure is clearer in Turtle or N-Triples:

```
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix vCard: <http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#> .

<http://somewhere/JohnSmith>
        vCard:FN  "John Smith" ;
        vCard:N   [ vCard:Family  "Smith" ;
                    vCard:Given   "John"
                  ] .
```

or equivalently:

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix vCard: <http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#> .

<http://somewhere/JohnSmith>
        vCard:FN  "John Smith" ;
        vCard:N   _:b0 .

_:b0    vCard:Family  "Smith" ;
        vCard:Given   "John" .
```

or in N-Triples:

```
<http://somewhere/JohnSmith> <http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#FN> "John Smith" .
<http://somewhere/JohnSmith> <http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#N> _:B99dd1c9aX2D9045X2D4719X2D8d7eX2D9f4043b9b757 .
_:B99dd1c9aX2D9045X2D4719X2D8d7eX2D9f4043b9b757 <http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#Family> "Smith" .
_:B99dd1c9aX2D9045X2D4719X2D8d7eX2D9f4043b9b757 <http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#Given> "John" .
```

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much!
and I'll update my library

Comment: Sorry! I am new here. I accept the answer when I just noticed I need to do it.